# Does upgrading to OSX Mountain Lion have any caveats for development using Xcode?

Tags: xcode, osx-mountain-lion

Like the title says, is there any issue Xcode developers should be aware of before switching to Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this answer your question?

[link](http://benjaminfleischer.com/2012/08/10/caveats-for-the-developer-when-upgrading-mac-osx-to-mountain-lion/)